# How can I get a copy of a ArrayList<String>() object instad of a refrence;

Tags: java

if I ge

```
ArrayList<String> myList;
// add some stuff to myList
ArrayList<String> copyOf=myList;
```

copy will be a reference to myList, thus if I change copyOf, myList will change to.
Hpw can I make coyyOf be a copy of myList, so if copyOf chnages, myList will not change.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(myList)` will give you a separate copy.

Comment: @StaticBeagle No need to clone the contents.

Comment: @StaticBeagle not a dupe.  That other one's about doing a deep copy.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Some of the top answers is pratically as you answered.

Comment: Then you should downvote them there.  My answer would be incorrect as an answer to that other question.

Comment: A more general comment: The problem you have is one of the things that drive people towards using immutable objects such as [ImmutableList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the constructor of `ArrayList` that takes a collection as a parameter.

```
List<String> myCopy = new ArrayList<>(theArrayListToCopy);
```

According to the Javadoc, this "Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator."